# CheckBox receives all events in Stack eventhough its not being clicked

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a Stack where I first add Button on and then Checkbox.

Checkbox only fills 1/4th of the space in the whole element but when I try to click the button anywhere within the group the checkbox receives all the events.

[image: View]

```
TextureRegionDrawable drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(tile.getTexture());
ImageButton button = new ImageButton(drawable, drawable);
Stack group = new Stack();

button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
                createTileEditor(tile);
        }
});

CheckBox box = new CheckBox("", skin);

tileGroup.add(box);
group.add(button);
group.add(box);
box.align(Align.bottom | Align.right);
group.pack();

boxes.put(box, tile);

tileTable.add(group).pad(2f);

if (counter++ > 0 && counter % 4 == 0) {
        tileTable.row();
}
```